# Validar un reporte si este no devuelve ningun dato. JAVA - JASPERREPORTS

Tags: java, java-swing, jasper-reports, ireport

Parece una problema sencillo pero esto me esta llevando una semana.. Pero bueno, yendo al caso, Cuando uno quiere generar un reporte, de jasperreports, y no devuelve ningún dato desde el motor de una Base de Datos (uso MySQL) se sabe que devuelve un mensaje de aviso directo desde jasper que dice "Este documento no tiene paginas" y por consiguiente sale una ventana como ejemplo de un pdf vació.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es validar o condicionar, por si acaso la base de datos no devuelva nada de datos, para que no salga el mensaje por defecto de aviso y después la ventana vacía.

Se que todos los que harían es agregar un excepción (try-catch) desde el método que uno creo para que se ejecute el reporte, pero a mi no me funciono.
Mi pregunta es, la validación se hace sobre el archivo de jasper (.jrxml) o desde la clase donde esta dicho metodo (es lo que hice). Cual seria la mejor manera de hacer el método para validar o condicionar correctamente. 
Les dejo el método donde llama para generar el reporte:

```
public void ReporteVentasSemanal(String fechainicio, String fechafinal) {
try {
    JasperReport ventassemanal;

    String ruta = "src\\Reportes\\Ventas_Semanal.jasper";

    Map parametros = new HashMap();

    parametros.put("FechaInicio", fechainicio);
    parametros.put("FechaFinal", fechafinal);

    ventassemanal = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(ruta);

    JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ventassemanal, parametros, cn);

    JasperViewer ver = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);

    ver.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    ver.setVisible(true);

} catch (JRException ex) {
    //Logger.getLogger(control_Reportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se obtuvo ningun dato.");
}
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias por cada aporte de su ayuda!

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es tu idea? ¿Que no muestre nada o que en lugar de aparecer la página en blanco aparezca otra cosa?

Comment: De lo que veo haces la consulta en el informe. ¿Por qué no haces la misma consulta *antes* de lanzar el informe y así ves si tiene datos?

Comment: Hola!, pido disculpas si no se entiende o no me especifique bien mi pregunta. Lo que quiero hacer, cuando se ejecute para generar el reporte, es que si en el caso si la base de datos no me devuelve ningun dato, poner una simple mensaje de aviso como por ejemplo "No se encontraron datos" y que no aparezca esa ventana con el pdf virtual vacio nada mas.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Muchas gracias por la idea, la verdad es que no se me paso por la cabeza. Estaba enfocado si el propio ireport, tenia una opcion parecida o lo que queria hacer, que lo tiene, pero seguia mostrando igual la pagina vacia. Con tu idea cree una consulta que devuelve true si tiene datos y muestra el diseño cargado y viceversa. Ahora lo puedo manipular. Saludos!